# How to detect Fragment change and change orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, mapfragment

I have this Activity container that will change fragments accordingly during the usage of the application.

```
public class MyTravelogueActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    //codes here
}
```

Can I ask if it's possible to check that if the current Fragment is of a MapFragment class, i want to change the orientation to **LANDSCAPE** only? And when I click on the back button or navigate somewhere else, orientation should go back to portrait. Currently all the fragments are displayed in portrait mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I believe the user should have the option to choose the desired orientation, but if you want to do that, you can use the [`setRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) method from the activity class.
Didn't test if, but something like this should work:
On the `onResume` method of your `MapFragment`, you can use

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(<Landscape Orientation>)
```

On the `onPause` method of your `MapFragment`, you can use

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(<Portrait Orientation>)
```

Replace `<Landscape Orientation>` and `<Portrait Orientation>` with the desired option from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html).